# How to isolate an HTML element from the rest of the document

Tags: html

In our case the "Description" attribute of a task can be entered in HTML by the end user. This HTML code can have its own css and styling. When I include this in our page, I do not want its style to affect the rest of the document. How do I achieve this? The browsers we support are Chrome, Firefox and IE8 and IE9.

Thanks.

Comment: Define that element's `css` and styles for only its `id` or `class-name`. So those css codes does `not` affect your page.

Comment: do you want to give him complete freedom of what he can write by html? if yes, he can insert ANY code that can change your page.

Comment: Yes, I want to give him complete freedom. I can strip out the script elements but I want to keep the styling on text entered by them as-is.  Let's say they want all their links to be shown in red. That's OK. Just that links on the rest of the page should not be affected by it.

Answer (score 0):

You could load it in an iframe. But you should really do some xss filtering, so that the user does not put in malicious scripts.